# Assimp Compilation Error Using CMake: GCC Cannot Compile Test Program

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++, mingw, assimp

I am trying to compile Assimp 5.0.1 for Windows 10 using CMake.  The C/C++ compilers I have through MinGW are GCC and G++.  If I understand the problem correctly, there is an issue with the MakeFile's whitespace somewhere.  The /CMakeTmp/ directory is empty, and I am sure the answer is right in front of me somewhere:

Console Output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):make -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_a4ec5\fast && Makefile:37: *** missing separator.  Stop.



  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (PROJECT)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

CMakeError.log:

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):make -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_165dc\fast && Makefile:37: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

CMakeOutput.log:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/3.20.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/3.20.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"
```

Comment: Have you tried to go into `Q:/programming/westy/src/lib/assimp-5.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp` directory, open `Makefile` and check its 37 line? The error message is about that line.

Comment: The directory CMakeTmp is unfortunately empty, and I am unable to locate the MakeFile it is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `-G` option did you use for `cmake`?
The `/nologo` parameter for `make` doesn't seem right, that looks like a Microsoft/MSVC parameter. If you didn't specify `-G` then CMake defaults to `-G"NMake Makefiles"` on Windows.

Make sure to use `cmake` flag `-G"MinGW Makefiles"` for `mingw32-make` or `-G"MSYS Makefiles"` if you use MSYS' `make`.

But to avoid all those make issues and improve speed `-GNinja` is the best solution, provided you have Ninja available (see https://ninja-build.org/).

Finally, you're still on MinGW GCC 9.2.0. Newer versions are available, see http://winlibs.com/ for standalone builds which also come with newer `mingw32-make`.

Comment: Ahh thank you!  This is all very helpful.

Comment: If it solved your issue, can you please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it?

Comment: Yep!  Sorry about that.